# Make severel http request cleverly in Android

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I have 3 functions:

```
A()
B()
C()
```

and all of them request data from several web services.
I want to make it all of them are called in same time. 
Not first A, after B, and after C.
A B and C should work in same time interval.
Any advice?

Comment: have a look at the this link https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html

Comment: Just create three different thread and execute parallel call to these three methods.

Comment: Thank you so much, immediately i'll look over

Comment: Or subclass and use AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html